# Python Argparse parse_known_args fails when short options are joined

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm using argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args to perform some heuristics on the command-line given to an external utility, while only specifying the relevant parts of its syntax in my Python code. However when known and unknown arguments are given in short form and are joined together in (as in `ls -lh`), it doesn't detect them.
Example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('-x', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('-y', action='store_true')
parser.parse_known_args(['-xy', '-z'])  # OK, gives: (Namespace(x=True, y=True), ['-z']
parser.parse_known_args(['-xyz'])       # Fails with: PROG: error: argument -y: ignored explicit argument 'z'
```

Is there a way to get it to make better heuristics in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around the issue by writing a function to separate arguments clustered together (with some simplifying assumptions):

```
import itertools
import re

def normalizeShortFormArgs(args):
    "Separate short form args clustered together (as in 'ls -lh') into individual args (as in 'ls -l -h')"
    shortArgsRe = re.compile(r"\-(\w+)")
    def normalizeToken(argToken):
        m = shortArgsRe.match(argToken)
        if m is None:
            return (argToken,)
        else:
            return ("-" + c for c in m.group(1))

    return type(args)(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(normalizeToken, args)))

# Example: normalizeShortFormArgs(["-k", "-lhZ", "-", "--other"])
# Gives: ['-k', '-l', '-h', '-Z', '-', '--other']
```

Answer (score 1):

I responded to a similar issue on https://bugs.python.org/issue32756.

As I noted there `argparse` documentation does not promise to handle this type of input as you want:

From the documentation, 16.4.4.1. Option value syntax

> For short options (options only one character long), the option and its value can be concatenated:
>
> Several short options can be joined together, using only a single - prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a value:

In your case 'z' is neither a short option nor a value for a short option, so it's rejected.

So yes, preprocessing the input is the only option.

---

'-xyz' where '-x' and '-y' are known but 'z' is not is inherently ambiguous.  Is it '-x -y -z', '-x -y z', '-x -y=z'.  `argparse` raise an error rather than make one of these assumptions.